# android studio errors with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Error in android studio is:

`Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavenCentral()'
Possible causes:`

The project 'testsdk' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.0.1 and sync project

The project 'testsdk' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

how can I resolved it?

Comment: Did you check this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063265/gradle-dsl-error-not-found-mavencentral)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle DSL error not found mavenCentral()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063265/gradle-dsl-error-not-found-mavencentral)